# How to refractor this code and get the average of all students overall mark in the array

Tags: java

**Client Class**

```
public class Assignment2Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int sum;
        String choice;
        String option;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("What is your option");
            option = reader.next();
            Student   [] Studentlist ;
            int numofStudent = 0;
            while("Add".equalsIgnoreCase(option))
            {      
               System.out.println("How many student would you like to enter: ");
                        numofStudent=reader.nextInt();
                        Studentlist=new Student [numofStudent];

                        for(int i=0;i<numofStudent;i++)
                        {
                            Studentlist[i] =new Student();
                            Studentlist[i].inputDetails();

                        }
                        System.out.println("What is your option");
                        choice = reader.next();
                        while("TotalAVG".equalsIgnoreCase(choice))
                        {
                            for(int i=0;i<Studentlist.length;i++)
                            {
                                Studentlist[i].avg();
                            }
                            System.out.println("What is your option");
                            choice = reader.next();
                        }


                        System.out.println("What is your option");
                        choice = reader.next();

            }

   //Input Method
    public void inputDetails()
       {
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Score of Assignemt 1:");
        ass01=reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Score of Assignemt 2:");
        ass02=reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Total Mark of Weekly Pratice Work:");
        weeklyWork=reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please Enter The Score of Final Exam:");
        finalExam=reader.nextInt();
       }

    //Average method
    void avg()
       {
       int count = 0;
       int overallMark =0;
       int sum = 0;
        overallMark = (ass01/5)+(ass02/5)+weeklyWork+(finalExam/2);
        sum = sum+overallMark;
        count = count +1;
        System.out.println("The average: "+(sum/count) );
       }
```

> I have the problem is when I try input TotalAVG,it show me two output
>
> The average: 50
>
> The average: 3

The Overall Mark is build in sub class,

1. How do I collect all the Overall Mark and do the average of it
2. How to refractor this code?

Answer (score 1):

in your `avg()` method:

1. you declare `int sum = 0;` and then add another variable to it: `sum = sum+overallMark;` so `sum` will always contain `overallMark`
2. another similar issue is with `count`: you declare it inside `avg()`: `int count = 0;` and then add 1: `count = count +1;` so it will always have value `1`

Comment: Thanks for reply,
 
How can I add the two average become one?